# Different events display different color(jQuery Full Calendar)

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have built up jQuery full calendar from http://www.arshaw.com/
Now I have fetched multiple events on calendar but I want to display event in different color for easily to get identical

for example 
Student events for green color,
Professor events for yellow color

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `backgroundColor` property **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RE3Mt/)**

```
events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1),
                backgroundColor: '#000'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d-2),
                backgroundColor: '#000'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            }
        ]
```

Similarly:

If you want to change the color of text of event you can use `textColor`

If you want to change the color of border of even you can use `borderColor`